# Microsoft office trying to update Org contact properties

Tags: azure, exchange-server

I am trying to update org properties including IMAddress. But when I try to update any properties(like address, email, etc) it says it is read-only. Is this supported via Graph API?

Ref link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/orgcontact-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

The permission section in the document says not supported, but they have an example that says it is available in beta.

also, is it possible to update imAddresses column in another way? I am able to update personal contact IM address via Graph but not for org contacts. For OrgContact IMaddress is not even exposed.

=====================

## {
"error": {
"code": "Request_BadRequest",
"message": "Property 'imAddresses' is read-only and cannot be set.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2021-09-30T05:43:11",
"request-id": "2c201f04-40e1-499a-b06f-6ad00465cc16",
"client-request-id": "931d3b51-8afa-e500-9023-0e11dd9c586b"
}
}
}

Comment: Hello, if the posted answer resolves your question, please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to update the `IMaddress` for org contacts as of now as its only `read-only` . You can only change/update the properties which are mentioned in [Microsoft Official Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/orgcontact-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#request-body).

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Note :** You can create a feedback/feature request for the same from [Microsoft Graph Support](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support).